# jquery alternative to change or keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which the user must initial a bunch of different sections.

```
<script>
  $.function(){
    $('.initialMe').change(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(id);
    }); 
  });
</script>

<?php
  echo "<div class='signature'>Initial Here:<input type='text' class='initialMe' id='sign[service1]' name='sign[service1]' size='4'></div>";
  echo "<div class='signature'>Initial Here:<input type='text' class='initialMe' id='sign[service2]' name='sign[service2]' size='4'></div>";
?>
```

I want to fire off an action when they are done initializing the text box.  I don't want to use change because they have to click off somewhere for event to be fired.  I don't want to use `keyup`, because event will fire after first letter of initials.  I do not know if user will use 2 letters or 3 for initials. This is not a submittable form.  Think of it as a legal document where the user has to initial different sections of the page.  What options do I have?

Comment: So, how do you know the user is done inputting? If not by reading the input and not by having the user move to a different input, perhaps you can tell he's done because he's not typing anymore, but how long should you wait? Measure his keystroke delay distribution and wait for five sigmas? Too complex. Five seconds? It's too long and not long enough at the same time. Twice as long as the user's known maximum? It's pretty easy to measure ridiculously high maxima and then you're screwed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `keyup` and `setTimeout`. What I am trying to say is, bind it in `keyup` and give some time for the user to feel like it's done and then check.

```js
$(function () {
  var tmr = 0;
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(tmr);
    tmr = setTimeout(function () {
      alert("Checking...");
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

This way, it is checked every time, but gives some time. When the user types again within a second, it clears the previous timer, so the check will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it on `blur()`?

If the user has clicked or tabbed away from the field then that gives an indication they're done imho.

Another option, if it's the same user initialing several parts of a form - you could wait until the first field is done, check with the user that it's correct, then don't do anything with the others until then initials match the first completed field.

Comment: `I don't want to use change because they have to click off somewhere for event to be fired.` This is same as `blur()`, agree?

Comment: Yeah it is, the question was more asking WHY it matters if they're clicking away- if there's more than one field on a form, at some point the field will `blur()`

Comment: Still, he needs a "different" way! LoL.